# How can I use JS or jQuery to run a function on DOM elements as they lazy load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, lazy-loading, setinterval

I use this basic interval and callback to run a function once a particular DOM element exists.

```
function ready(elem, callback) {
    let loaded = setInterval(function(){
        if ( document.querySelectorAll(elem).length ) {
            clearInterval(loaded);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

ready('elem', function(){
    //code here
});
```

Now I need a way to run a function on elements one by one as they lazyload into the DOM. As I scroll down the page, images lazy load in with a bogus src attribute like this: `<img src="/blank.jpg">`. Then a script I do not have control of runs and the src is adjusted to be the actual image. So, I need a script to wait for these lazy loaded images to exist, THEN wait for the source to not be bogus anymore.

I know the src is no longer bogus when it contains a certain substring - example "foo": `<img src="/imgnamefoo.jpg">`. I know how many images are supposed to hit the page because I pull the quantity from a global object. Also, the images have IDs that are numbered (id="someid_1"), but I prefer not to rely on that like I currently am. My current method is to wait for the last image to exist, check for the substring on that image, then run the function on all the images simultaneously. However, I would like to run it as the images appear, so there is less of a delay waiting for the user to scroll all the way down to the last image. They would simply be addressed as they appear.

My current code that waits for the last img to exist:

```
window.quantity = object.images.length;

function ready(elem, callback) {
    let loaded = setInterval(function(){
        var src = document.querySelectorAll(elem)[0].getAttribute('src');
        if ( src.indexOf('foo') !== -1 ) {
            clearInterval(loaded);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

ready('#someid_' + window.quantity, function(){
    // code here
});
```

If 7 images were expected to lazy load in, the function would fire when this element exists:

`<img id="someid_7" src="/imgnamefoo.jpg">`

EDIT:
I have tried this to try and trigger my code when the src attribute was rewritten:

```
$(document).on('load', 'img[src*="blank.jpg"]', function(){
    //code here    
});
```

And I also tried this, suspecting that maybe the img element was being completely rewritten or replaced in the DOM. This one looks for the new src:

```
$(document).on('load', 'img[src*="foo.jpg"]', function(){
    //code here    
});
```

Both were unsuccessful.

EDIT: SOLVED!
This is the code that ended up working:

```
(function(){
    const daReviewItems = digitalData.cart.item.length;

    function whenRemoved(element, callback) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.querySelectorAll(element).length < daReviewItems) {
                callback();
            }
        }, 100);
        return interval;
    }
    function whenExists(element, callback) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.querySelectorAll(element).length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                callback();
            }
        }, 100);
        return interval;
    }
    var loop_id = 0;
    whenRemoved('elem',function(){
        if (loop_id) return;
        loop_id = whenExists('img',function(){
            //SOME CODE HERE
            loop_id = 0;
        });
    });
})();
```

It is wrapped in an anonymous function to keep it global scope. Basically, it waits for 'elem' to not exist, then it checks if the img I want to edit does exist. If it does, then any imgs that I haven't added the 'elem' class to yet, get the function run on them. So, on initial load, 'elem' doesn't exist because I haven't added that class yet, so the code fires. Then, if the imgs get removed or reloaded, my 'elem' class is removed, so it fires again and waits for the imgs again. The loop_id checks the iteration and keeps the code from infinitely looping. I have to credit a developer I know for helping with this. He doesn't have a user here, but he deserves credit. So, thanks!

Comment: Is the load event fired any time the src changes? Because the images are loaded in with transparent 1px images in the src. The hook I'm looking for would be when the src changes. If that is the case I can just create a document event that looks for images with the right ID to have a new load event. I may also need a way to make sure the load event it grabs is not the first one... Can you elaborate on your advice?

Comment: Sorry, no. The object only serves to let me know how many images will be lazy loading onto the page. It is dynamic, based on the individual visitor. Some visitors will see 5 images, others maybe just 1. I currently use the image quantity to know when they are all present on the page, even if they still haven't been given the correct src.

Comment: you have to use mutationObserver  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: In this case I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this without using mutationObserver.